# Fighting game in Java

Tags: java, beginner, battle-simulation

I want a better way to do the `if` statements, and if there is a better way to do it. How is it more efficient? Is there something like a `switch` statement in Java that would help?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class main {



    private static boolean playing = false;
    private static int enemyHealth = 100;
    private static int playerHealth = 100;
    private static double enemyChoice = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 3);
    private static String pName;



    public static void checkHealth(){
        if(enemyHealth <= 0){
            System.out.println("Mother! "+pName+" wins!");
            playing = false;
        }else if(playerHealth <= 0){
            System.out.println(pName+" has fallen! Rocky wins!");
            playing = false;
        }
    }






    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String wantPlay;
        // asking the player if they want to play
        System.out.println("Want to play a fighting game?: ");
        wantPlay = user_input.next();

        // if the player chooses to play, it wil lstart the game loop
        if(wantPlay.equals("Yes") || wantPlay.equals("yes")){

            System.out.println("What do you want your name to be?: ");
            pName = user_input.next();

            System.out.println("Hey folks!, were going to have an exiting game today!");
            System.out.println("In the left corner, we have Rocky Balboa!!!!!");
            System.out.println("and in the right corner, we have "+pName+"!!!!!");
            System.out.println("");

            playing = true;
        }

        while(playing == true){


            System.out.println("Rocky has "+enemyHealth+" health remaining.");
            System.out.println("You have "+playerHealth+" health remaining.");

            String action;
            System.out.println("What would you like to do? (a)upper cut (b)side punch (c)down cut: ");
            action = user_input.next();
            // a = 1     b = 2      c = 3
            enemyChoice = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 3);
            checkHealth();

            if(action.equals("a") && enemyChoice == 2){
                checkHealth();
                System.out.println("oohh! and "+pName+" throws a devistating blow into Rocky!");
                enemyHealth-=10;
                checkHealth();

            }else if (action.equals("a") && enemyChoice == 3){
                checkHealth();
                System.out.println("OH! "+pName+" JUST GOT SMASHED!");
                playerHealth -=10;
                checkHealth();
            }else if (action.equals("b") && enemyChoice == 3){
                checkHealth();
                System.out.println("Rocky just got smashed!!!!");
                enemyHealth-=10;
                checkHealth();
            }else if (action.equals("b") && enemyChoice == 1){
                checkHealth();
                System.out.println(pName+" better step up his game!");
                playerHealth-=10;
                checkHealth();
            }else if (action.equals("c") && enemyChoice == 1){
                checkHealth();
                System.out.println("Rockey just got pucnhed so hard that he might not even know he exists!");
                enemyHealth-=10;
                checkHealth();
            }else if (action.equals("c") && enemyChoice == 2){
                checkHealth();
                System.out.println(pName+" Just got smashed!");
                playerHealth -=10;
                checkHealth();
            }else if(action.equals("a") && enemyChoice == 1){
                System.out.println("Their fists collided! this is intense!");
            }else if(action.equals("b") && enemyChoice == 2){
                System.out.println("Their fists collided! this is intense!");
            }else if (action.equals("c") && enemyChoice == 3){
                System.out.println("Their fists collided! this is intense!");

            }



        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Yes. Switch exists in java too. You could ignore case of yes while checking equality

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do a Switch Statement to reduce the else-ifs you have.

```
Switch(action)
{
    case "a": Switch(enemyChoice)
              {
              case 2:
                   System.out.println("oohh! and "+pName+" throws a devistating blow into Rocky!");
                   enemyHealth-=10;
                   checkHealth();
              }
              case 3:
                   System.out.println("OH! "+pName+" JUST GOT SMASHED!");
                   enemyHealth-=10;
                   checkHealth();
              }
    case b:
etc....
}
```

Also is there any need to check health before you take away health? you remove health, then check, then disable play. you aren't alive then die before making an action I assume.

Comment: yeah, i was still kind of testing the checkHealth thing, and realized that. that is why there is one at the top and bottom of each if/else if statement. i just never removed the first ones

Comment: Surely each of the cases in your switch statement requires a *break* keyword to terminate the enclosing case? Missing these will result in all of the following cases being executed

Answer (score 4):

Whenever you have a long list of `if-else` statements then you should consider whether an `enum` is more appropriate. In your case you seem to have some pretty clear logic that could be encapsulated better that way.

Here's an example to get your started:

```
public enum Action {
    UPPERCUT("a", 1, "Fists Collide", "Devastating Blow", "Blah blah"),
    JAB("b", 2, "Smashed", "Blocked", "Blah blah"),
    HAYMAKER("c", 3, "Blah", "blah", "blah");

    private final String code;
    private final int enemyBlockAction;
    private final String[] messages;

    Action(String code, int enemyBlockAction, String... messages) {
        this.code = code;
        this.enemyBlockAction = enemyBlockAction;
        this.messages = messages;
    }

    public static Action actionForCode(String code) {
        for (Action action: values()) {
            if (action.code.equals(code))
                return action;
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No action for code " + code);
    }

    public perform() {
        int enemyAction = random.nextInt(messages.length);
        System.out.println(messages[enemyAction]);
        if (enemyAction != enemyBlockAction) {
            enemyHealth -= 10;
            checkHealth();
        }
    }
}
```

You can then replace all your conditions with `Action.actionForCode(code).perform()`